# Need reference code for SMO in C# SQL Server 2008

Tags: c#, sql-server-2008, smo

I googled but cannot find proper simple code for using backup database full and restore the backup, using defaults by using C#.

I am using C# Visual Studio 2008 and SQL Server 2008 R2 evalution but I guess SQL Server 2005 and C# will work too.

The Microsoft site doesn't have code regarding it, it only show description of `Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.Smo` Namespace......

Comment: VB.NET any good to you? http://www.shabdar.org/sql-server-backup-utility.html

Answer (score 2, accepted):

MSDN has a topic [Getting Started in SMO](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms162547.aspx) that covers a lot of ground - there's also a topic called [Programming Specific Tasks](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms162175.aspx) which shows how to do certain common tasks in C# with SMO.

And there's a whole series of [Getting Started with SMO in SQL Server 2005](http://www.sqldbatips.com/showarticle.asp?ID=34) which still very much applies to the 2008 and 2008 R2 versions of SQL Server.

Here's another [Getting started with SQL Server Management Objects (SMO)](http://www.mssqltips.com/tip.asp?tip=1826) article to get you up to speed.

Answer (score 0):

Here is an example with VB.NET
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.sqlserver.management.smo.restore.aspx
You can use a converter to get C#:
http://www.developerfusion.com/tools/convert/csharp-to-vb/